# Java DecimalFormat default format

Tags: java

I am using the following to parse and convert a decimal:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale(someLocale));
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.00", otherSymbols);
```

Is there any way to avoid specifying a pattern and use the default one?

Comment: @Fede I can't find something specifying the locale without the format.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.

Comment: Isn't String#format using some default pattern?